# The search box and an additional button not aligned in a navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navbar. inside it I have a search form and an additional button. The problem is that the button not aligned with other elements in the navbar: 
[image]

Here is my code. Anyone sees why they shouldn't be aligned?

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Bootstrap 3 </title>
        <link href ="css/bootstrap.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href ="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href ="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href ="css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head> 
    <body> 

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">

          <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="navbar-header">

        <!-- box -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>

            </div>

        <!-- Single button -->
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Action <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

          </div>

        </nav>

    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a snippet or fiddle replicating the issue. We don't have anything to work with without your css.

Comment: Right click on the "Action" element and click "Inspect element". Look at the elements and their styling. You can figure stuff like this out quite easily if you know how to inspect elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the class navbar-btn to your button:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macsupport/zfqd6z1v/)

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-btn btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Action <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
```

Comment: Amazing! Is there a general rule for this? Like any element needs to inherent the style of its parent?